# Optional argument in optional argument causing errors

Tags: macros

The following Latex fails to build with mysterious errors, the first one being `Argument of \\bred has an extra }`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\restr}[2]{{\ifx\\#2\\ #1 \else #1|#2 \fi}}
\newcommand{\opensg}[2][]{\restr{\mathcal{T}\ifx\\#2\\ \else_{#2}\fi}{#1}}
\newcommand{\opens}[1][]{\opensg[#1]{}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\closureg}{ O{\opens} O{P} m }{\overline{#3}(#1)_{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\closure}{ O{} O{P} m }{\closureg[{\opens[#1]}][#2]{#3}}
\newcommand{\bred}[2][\opens]{#2^{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\closure[{\bred[A]{B}}]{C}$

\end{document}
```

It can be made to build with `$\closure[{\bred{B}}]{C}$` instead.

What is the problem, and how can I get the optional argument `[A]` to work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems quite a complicated set of commands… Anyway, stick to `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\restr}{mm}{#1\IfBlankF{#2}{|#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\opensg}{O{}m}{\restr{\mathcal{T}\IfBlankF{#2}{_{#2}}}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\opens}{O{}}{\opensg[{#1}]{}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\closureg}{ O{\opens} O{P} m }{\overline{#3}(#1)_{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\closure}{ O{} O{P} m }{\closureg[{\opens[#1]}][#2]{#3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bred}{O{\opens}m}{#2^{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\closure[\bred[A]{B}]{C}$

\end{document}
```

Loading `xparse` hasn't been necessary since October 2020.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this has been bugging me for years! The problem seems to be the use of `\ifx` specifically. Replacing it with `\IfBlankF` gets rid of the build errors, and those additional braces in optional arguments get the look right. I'll convert all my macros to `\NewDocumentCommand` to be sure.